# Can't echo the username in the same page?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build a Login page ( simple )
every time I run the website I got this error code

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\project1\index.php on line 14

on the screen in the web that I made.

Here is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <form action="Login.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 <br>
 <?php echo $_GET["name"] ?>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not get parameter with name "name".
Make check for that like"

```
....
</form>
<br>
<?php if(isset($_GET['name'])){
        echo  $_GET['name'];
    } ?>
```

Also for login better use `POST` method

Comment: thanks, even that its old but it helped me before when I just know about stackoverflow and learning PHP